# A flow $f$ is maximum $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists$ an empty $s$-$t$ cut

Tags: graph-theory, duality-theorems, network-flow

Given a flow network $(G,\mu,s,t)$. I am thinking about the following statement.
A flow $f$ is maximum $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists$ an empty $s$-$t$ cut
I know "$\Rightarrow$ is correct, but also "$\Leftarrow$"?

Comment: What do you mean by an empty $s-t$ cut?